# Parent scope not triggering child rerender in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

i have a prent comp and a child cmponent. as follows

**parent**

```
export class ExpressionMenu extends Component {
 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  state = {
    apiArray: [],
  }

  updateStateFromChild = (arrayType, propertyType, value) => {
    let { apiArray } = this.state
    let currentArray = []
    let idx = apiArray.findIndex((q)  => q.id === id)
    currentArray = apiArray
    
    switch(propertyType) {
      case 'updateObject': {
        currentArray = value
        break;
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      apiArray: currentArray 
    })
  }
  

  render () {
    const {
     apiArray
    } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div >
          <div>
            <ApiPanel 
                apiArray={apiArray} 
                updateStateFromChild={this.updateStateFromChild} 
            />
            
         </div>  
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}  
  ExpressionMenu.propTypes = {
    styleOverride: PropTypes.object,
    eventHandler: PropTypes.func,
  };
  
  export default ExpressionMenu;
```

**child**

```
export class ApiPanel extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props),
  }

  removeApi = (id) => {
    let { apiArray } = this.props
    apiArray = apiArray.filter((q) => q.id !== id);
    this.props.updateStateFromChild('api', 'updateObject', apiArray)
  };

  addApi = () => {
    let { apiArray } = this.props
    const id = uniqid();
    let obj = {}
    obj.id = id
    apiArray.push(obj)
    this.props.updateStateFromChild('api', 'updateObject', apiArray)
  };

  render() {
    const { apiArray } =  this.props
   
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {
          apiArray.map((apiObj, i) =>
           <div key={i} >
            <span onClick={() => this.removeApi(apiObj.id) } className={[classes.deleteRow,'material-icons'].join(' ')}>
                close
              </span>
              
                <div>
                  <label><b>Hi</b></label>
                </div>
              
               <div onClick={this.addApi}>+Add Api</div>
        }
       
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ApiPanel.propTypes = {
  apiArray: PropTypes.array,
  updateStateFromChild: PropTypes.func
}

export default ApiPanel
```

Now when i call addApi(), it updates the parent but doesnt rerenders the child.
But when i call removeApi() , it updates parent as well as rerenders the child component properly.

in the first case when i manually reload the componnt i can see the change.

Dont understand why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your `addApi` function.

```
addApi = () => {
    let { apiArray } = this.props
    this.props.updateStateFromChild('api', 'updateObject', [...apiArray, {id : uniqid()} ])
  };
```

You need to return an enriched copy of your array

Comment: thanks a ton dude. I have a follow up question too. I ll post it here soon

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are updating the stating using arrays, objects. We need to always create a new array [...array], a new object {...obj}. Because if we update value in the array or obj without creating it won't change the reference value hence it assumes the state is not update and won't re-render.

Comment: why did the removeApi() function workk then? I am just wondering.

Comment: I can't tell exactly until I see the values in the apiArray variable.